# How to add Windows 2019 server to 2008 R2 and migrate DC

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2019

I have two Windows Server 2019 servers that I need to add to Server 2008 R2 domain.

It is not possible to add 2019 server to 2008 R2 domain without enabling SMB 1.0 client, and I would like to skip having SMB 1.0 at all on the domain. (For printer scan locations I will use either an isolated VM or internal FTP server.)

The procedure I devised is as follows:

- enable SMB 1.0 client on both servers and add them to domain
- migrate DC roles from old server to new
- remove old server
- remove SMB 1.0 from new server machines
- profit? :-)

Is this procedure OK?

I will have a number of Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 10 machines on the network, which should all be able to connect to new domain correctly?

Any tip or info is appreciated, as I am trying not o have to recreate entire domain from scratch.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Anyway, don't have time to wait for an answer. I compared settings with Server 2016, and see that it has SMB1 enabled by default. So I installed SMB clients on both servers and added them to domain.

I am currently processing updates and such, and will soon proceed to promote one to DC and other one to RDS.

Will post back how it worked.

Interesting quirk - you can't access add to domain using new settings, it is a bug or whatever, but need to go to advanced system settings that are buried deep now.

Comment: That's quite a leap! Would be nice to hear how this succeed.

Comment: Will post back. I tested a bit around and it is indeed possible to join to 2008 R2 if SMB 1.0 is enabled. What is interesting is that 2019 will join Domain functional level 2008 R2, but not out of the box, but you have to enable old SMB. Without it it doesn't work. As it stands now, I will probably replicate everything using SMB1 jump-over, and then turn off old systems. There will be some XP clients that will have to go and I expect all Canon MFP machines to stop working over SMB. Not sure about that yet, tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The devised procedure worked flawlessly:

1. enable SMB 1.0
2. add to domain
3. install AD DC in roles ad features
4. PowerShell: Move-ADDirectoryServerOperationMasterRole -Identity SERVERNAME -OperationMasterRole SchemaMaster, DomainNamingMaster, PDCEmulator, RIDMaster, InfrastructureMaster

Also to note: IP should be fixed, On both server DNS primary should be new DC, and don't forget to update the DHCP setting to set DC as first DNS server.